# handling backslash \" in csv Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which contains column values as such : \JIMMY'S PALACE"  and "JIMMY'S FLOOR"I am able to remove the " and \ via pandas which leaves me with the value as such:  JIMMYS PALACE and JIMMYS FLOOR without quotes(') although I want 'S as well but I can live without the apostrophe S , I need to further processing of the file how to make sure that the text is enclosed in quotes as while trying to read the file I am getting an error.

I have used the below to remove the " from the text :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df).replace('\\",'',regex=True)
```

which gives the output as such : JIMMYS PALACE  and JIMMYS FLOOR I want the output as

'JIMMYS PALACE'

'JIMMYS FLOOR' within the single quotes('), any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post sample of your original dataframe

Comment: Sample dataframe :[{'space':'abc123','name':\JIMMY'S PLACE\"}]

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('\\', '')
```